# Subquery returned more than 1 value. Trigger error in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I run the following query:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Tickerprice
ON Ticket 
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
    UPDATE Ticket
    SET Totalmoney = (CASE 
                         WHEN (SELECT Age FROM CUSTOMER) < 2 
                            THEN 0
                         WHEN (SELECT Age FROM CUSTOMER) < 12 
                            THEN (Tax + ((SELECT price FROM FLIGHTS) * 75 / 100))
                         ELSE (Age + (SELECT price FROM FLIGHTS))
                      END)
    FROM
        FLIGHTS, CUSTOMER, TICKET,
        (SELECT FLID FROM inserted) AS I,
        (SELECT IDCus FROM inserted) AS H
    WHERE
        FLIGHTS.FLID = TICKET.FLID 
        AND CUSTOMER.IDCus = TICKET.IDCus 
        AND TICKET.FLID = I.FLID 
        AND TICKET.IDCus = H.IDCus
GO

INSERT INTO TICKET (FLID, IDCus) 
VALUES ('CMA001', '01')
```

I get the following error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Any ideas?

Comment: The error is telling you the problem (for example you have `when (select Age from CUSTOMER)` which will only work if you have **only** 1 customer). But there are far more fundament problems here, such as the use of 30 year old join syntax, that was replaced 27 years ago, that you appear to be selecting from `inserted` twice in the `FROM` and then join to `ticket` still, and that you appear to be wanting to store aggregated values (which is not a good idea either). Seems like you should have a `VIEW` with these aggregated values, if you must.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: You would be far better off telling us what your actual goal is here. Provide us with some sample data, and expected results (as formatted as text, not images), and we can show you a "better" way of doing to, or explain the flaws we may see in your design.

Comment: There are so many bad design choices here. Why are you storing Age in the Customer table? Not sure if that is the person's age or the length of time the customer has been a customer. But either way you should calculate this when you need based on a fixed date, either birthdate or creationdate. Subqueries all over the place instead of using the values found by joins.

Comment: Clearly the OP went to the school where once you join a place, you never age, @SeanLange . We have an employee at the office who was 27 when they joined (10 years ago). They still proclaim they are 27 now. Must be the same logic. :)

Comment: @Larnu I need to go to work there. I am afraid that 27 passed me by a long time ago but I would be ok with slowing down the process for awhile anyway.